# Send a file using %userprofile% to a ftp using batch command

Tags: batch-file, ftp

Just make my script to send files to a `.ftp` folder and it's working well, follow bellow:

```
@echo off & SetLocal
( echo open ftp.xxxxx.com.it
echo username
echo password
echo put %userprofile%\Desktop\%date:/=-%.zip
echo bye 
)> %temp%\ftpsend.dat
ftp -s:%temp%/ftpsend.dat
del /f /s /q %temp%\ftpsend.dat
pause
```

But using `%userprofile%` it can't set the user. My computer username is `!Karen Dallalibera!` maybe is beacause the `!` in the username....but don't have`DelayExpansion`, so i don't know.

I want use `%userprofile%`, `%homepath%`, etc.

There's a way to use it?

---

Got it, using `"`. But there's another problem: I want upload the file into a especific folder, i tried as below:

```
    @echo off & SetLocal
    ( echo open ftp.xxxxx.com.it
    echo username
    echo password
    cd \Karen D.\Test\
    echo put "%userprofile%\Desktop\%date:/=-%.zip"
    echo bye 
    )> %temp%\ftpsend.dat
    ftp -s:%temp%/ftpsend.dat
    del /f /s /q %temp%\ftpsend.dat
    pause
```

I wanted to upload the files to the folder `\Karen D.\Test\`
But the script is saving on the main folder of the `ftp`.
How can i set the specific folder for uploading?

Comment: Should your first line be : `echo OPEN ftp://ftp.xxxxxx.com.it/ > ftpcommands.txt` so that it creates the file as a new one, rather than appending to an existing one?

Comment: "nothing happens" is unlikely. Does `cmd` or `ftp` generate an error message? Is the file created?

Comment: What Operating system are you running on? Is the FTP command installed?

Comment: It says the host in unknown (but is right, already checked), i use Windows 7.

Comment: check my last edit!

Comment: If you've got a new question - please ask a new question. Don't vandalize your own question by changing the title and content.

Comment: @LotPings I ask you to delet your answer, for me delet the question and create another one. As you marked as duplicated,  this question already exists and doesn't matter to anyone.

Comment: So let it be and post a new question. It will eventually get deleted automatically anyway, as it's closed and has negative score.

Answer (score 1):

Don't precede literal user/password with anything

```
( echo OPEN ftp.xxxxxx.com.it/
  echo username
  echo password
  echo put %userprofile%\Desktop\%date:/=-%.zip
  echo quit
) >ftpcommands.txt
FTP -s:ftpcommands.txt
```

Comment: It says the host `ftp://ftp.xxxxxx.com.it/`is unknown...but is right. Already checked it

Comment: try without protocol `ftp://` otherwise check  url/username password

Comment: Tried, but still says the host is unknown. But i already checked all, it's right.

Comment: I suggest you do a connection manually without script and enter the data on request, do you get numbered message (220/200/331) ?

Comment: I can open it manually, it's open normally. I didn't get any message. It's so much strange...

Comment: As the ftp port is known, I'd do a last try with `open xxxxxx.com.it` there should be a response.

Comment: Error 530 appeared

Comment: That's an error msg you could google for.

Comment: check my last edit!